# Converting java date object to milliseconds in JSTL

Tags: java, date, jstl

How can I convert a java date to milliseconds in JSTL? I tried using `<fmt:formatDate/>` but with no success. Please let me know any way to achieve this.

Comment: Try simply `date.time`. Does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just invoke [`Date#getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29).

```html
<p>The date property of a bean in milliseconds: ${bean.date.time}</p>
```

JSTL is not necessary in this context, unless you're running a prehistoric JSP 1.x beast, then you'd need to display it using `<c:out>` as EL in template text was not supported back then.